# AFT - Where is Android device mounted automatically on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, android, file-transfer

Having read [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android), I decided to give AFT a try, so I installed it by `sudo pacman -S android-file-transfer`, connected the device (OnePlus 3T) to the computer through USB, set it to "Transfer files mode", and then opened AFT. So far so good, I see all folders inside my device, I can select files and dowload them. I haven't tried uploading, but I think everythig's ok.

Except that I'd prefer to browse the device in the terminal, so that I can make use of regexp to move stuff from/to the device.

I've found the following

```
$ ll /dev/disk/by-id
...
usb-OnePlus_Device_Driver_5abf662b-0:0 -> ../../sr0
...
```

but when I try

```
$ mkdir mount_here
$ sudo mount /dev/sr0 mount_here
```

all I see is this

```
$ ll mount_here
total 18466
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root   root       2048 Sep  7  2016  ./
drwx------ 1 enrico enrico      912 Jun 17 15:34  ../
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root   root    6538856 Mar  3  2015 'AndroidFileTransfer(OSX).dmg'*
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root   root   12320875 Sep  5  2016  OnePlus_USB_Drivers_Setup.exe*
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root   root      45056 Jun  3  2015  OnePlus_setup.exe*
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root   root        794 Jun 30  2015  adb_config_Linux_OSX.sh*
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root   root         97 Jun  3  2015  autorun.inf*
```

Comment: Run `mount` before and after attaching the device to see what changes. If nothing changes, you can always use `aft-mtp-mount` to mount it anywhere

Comment: `mount` gives the same result before and after attaching the device; the same also after setting _transfer files_ from Android. Then `aft-mtp-mount mount_here` gives `Device::Find failed:Device is already used by another process` if I set _transfer files_ on the device, `connect failed: no MTP device found` if I had not.

Answer (score 2):

Use `adb` to connect to your device in a CLI.

### Prerequisites

Enable `Settings > Developer options > USB Debugging` on your phone.

Install the drivers.

```
$ cd mount_here
$ ./adb_config_Linux_OSX.sh
```

### Usage

Check if your device is found by adb:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
bada5535    device
```

Now you can browse your device with:

```
$ adb shell
OnePlus7TPro:/ $ cd storage/self/primary
OnePlus7TPro:/storage/self/primary $ ls
Alarms Android DCIM Documents Download Movies Music Notifications Pictures Podcasts Ringtones
```

Move files with:

```
$ adb pull <path>

$ adb push <source-path> <target-path>
```

### Trouble shooting

If you see this message:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
bada5535    no permissions; see [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html]
```

Try to start the adb server as root:

```
$ adb kill-server
$ sudo adb start-server
```

Comment: I'd really like to test your answer, but at the moment when I USB-connect the phone to the PC, I don't get the option, on the phone, for "file transfer" anymore. Therefore the command `ll /dev/disk/by-id` does not even show the phone, and there's nothing I can `mount`. Can you advice on this?

Comment: I'm referring to the option (in the dropdown) to choose what to do with the USB connection (file transfer, and other 2 or 3 possible choices). I remember that thing, but now it's no more there, regardless of the _USB debugging_ option status.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis There could be multiple causes and I'm not sure if I can advise on that, have you checked ` Settings > Storage > USB Computer Connection`?

Comment: Together with _USB debugging_, I have found _Settings > System > Developer options > Default USB configuration_, which lists _File Transfer_, _USB tethering_, _MIDI_, _PTP_, _No data transfer_. I think these are the options that I should see in the dropdown when the phone is connected to the PC via USB. However I still don't see anything in the dropdown, and selecting _File Transfer_ here where I've just found it, doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I suggest asking another question here on unix.SE because your issue is probably unrelated to your original question.

Comment: I agree that the question is unrelated, and I agree I should post it separately. However I need time to check what the appropriate place is (unix, superuser, android, ...), becuse the question is more about the phone, and not about programming at all.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I think [android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/) will be the best place, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is

> to browse the device in the terminal, so that I can make use of regexp to move stuff from/to the device.

on arch, I found that smple-mptfs in the AUR ( https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/simple-mtpfs/ ) actually works. This provides a single command simple-mtpfs and its man page. If even that is too much to read, here is a self-explanatory script posted by user teckk to the Newbie Corner of the arch wiki 
( https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1729381#p1729381)

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

#Script for simple-mtpfs    
PS3=$'\nSelect an option.: '

#mount directory
dir="$HOME/phone"

while :; do
    clear
    options="Quit List_Device Mount Umount"
    select opt in $options; do
        case $opt in
            Quit) clear; exit
            ;;

            List_Device) simple-mtpfs --list-devices
            ;;

            Mount) simple-mtpfs "$dir" -o enable-move; echo "Mounted to "$dir"" 
            ;;

            Umount) fusermount -u "$dir"; echo "Unmounted" 
            ;;
        esac
    done
done
```

Note that libmtp is a prerequisite for simple-mtpfs, and that the mount point of the above script (default is $HOME/phone) must exist before you run the script.

Spelled out in even more detail:
Here is the full set of commands I entered into a terminal  (starting in the directory which I use to house AUR packages) to go from "nothing" to satisfying the requirement above:

```
sudo pacman -S libtmtp
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/simple-mtpfs.git
cd simple-mtpfs
makepkg -si
#when prompted to confirm install of package simple-mtpfs, type "Y"

#create script droidfile with above text and make it executable

#to mount the phone at $HOME/phone
mkdir $HOME/phone
( echo 3 ; echo 1) |    droidfile
```

At this point, i can use a coreutils like ls etc and any file manager on $HOME/phone. 
Note that without the "enable-move" option to simple-mtpfs , you won't be able to use mv. And if you do enable it, it can be very slow.

to unmount, just

```
(echo 4; echo 1) | droidfile
```